# Ambiguous call to_string - is it possible?

Tags: string, c++11, operator-overloading, tostring

That is my printing overloaded operator:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Card& card) {
        string str;
        if(cardValueCorrect(card._value)){
            str += to_string(card._value); ////////////////////////////////////
        } else {
            str += card._identier;
        }
        str += suitToChar(card._suit);
        return os << str;
    }
```

Can somebody help with this ambiguous call, Card_value is just an ordinary int, I don't see what can be there ambiguous ?

```
Card.cpp: In function âstd::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Card&)â:
Card.cpp:160: error: call of overloaded âto_string(const int&)â is ambiguous
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2616: note: candidates are: std::string std::to_string(long double)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2610: note:                 std::string std::to_string(long long unsigned int)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2604: note:                 std::string std::to_string(long long int)
```

Comment: can you show us more code?

Comment: and what is this little "a" with accent above?

Comment: Try putting "std::" in front of "to_string".

Comment: about the a, no idea, ignor it.

Comment: My mistake, adding std:: didn't change anything, still have that trouble.

Comment: even if i put a simple integer number it gives me the same error

Comment: One way to handle it is to make casting to (long long int), but there is a handle for in type in to_string function, so it's strange.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Ensure that all headers are included:
`<string>`
`<iostream>`

2 - Try to remove your `using namespace std` line and use explicit std namespace specification.

3 - Just for testing purposes try to use explicit template specialization:
`std::to_string<int>(card._value);`

Comment: I think the problem it doesn't see to_string (and finds it in other place where there isn't an int type for it or something), because all the headers ok, I've used only explicit using std::to_string and so ... 
But when I try to write std::to_string<int>(card._value);
It says that to_string couldn't be resolved

Comment: Can you provide more information? Compiler and platform you are using, your compiler flags and a bit more about your code structure. Otherwise it is really hard to say anything more. Wrong --std flag flag maybe.